# Zabbix auto registration using metadata fails with a "cannot link template(s)" error message

Tags: monitoring, zabbix

I have a Linux host with a specific metadata value (linuxhosts) which I have set in the zabbix_agentd.conf
I also set an Action with an auto registration event source with the following configuration:

Conditions:
Host metadata like linuxhosts

Operations:
Add to host groups SystemTestLinux
Link to template Linux system test template

The issue is that the host is not being linked to "Linux system test" template.
Looking at zabbix_server.log, I see the following error: 
`cannot link template(s) "Linux system test" to host "xxxxx": conflicting item key "net.if.discovery" found`. The template "Linux system test" is not linked to any other template and I do not have any discovery rule enabled. 
It is also important to note that I currently have a lot of Windows hosts that are linking fine to templates, the problem only occurs with Linux hosts.

Comment: Which Zabbix version? Try linking the template to that host manually - does it still fail? Is that the only template your action attempts the linkage with, and is that the only matching action?

Comment: I am using version 3.4.12 Revision 83229
Linking the host manually works fine but unfortunately its not a solution for my case as I too many hosts. 
Yes, its the only template that this action creates linkage to and this is the only matching metadata rule. 
I have other actions that link to other templates that work fine.

Comment: Sounds weird. Can you please check that the action indeed links the template you think it is linking, and the exact same you tested manually? Assuming "Linux system test" is a test template that is not important, please try deleting the `net.if.discovery` LLD rule from it and seeing whether it gets auto-linked by the server then.

Comment: @Richlv I know, it actually sounds like a bug and I've opened one for them. They asked me to run a query and return the results which I did and since then I didn't hear from them. (I still have the issue). Here is a link to the bug: https://support.zabbix.com/browse/ZBX-14722

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved with a workaround. 
The issue is that Zabbix was unable to handle two very similar metadata strings that linked each agent to its appropriate group and template.

For example, if you have one agent reporting "productionDev" and another agent reporting "productionDevOps" you might end up having the same issue that I have. To work around the issue, you will need to have two conditions for each auto registration action:
like "productionDev"
notlike "productionDevOPS"
This will make sure that your "productionDev" agents will join their appropriate groups and templates.